# Firefox wont show colors, IE shows correct

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, colors

im just beginner at CSS, so i have a problem i wrote a simple code, IE shows correctly, but Firefox didint, how can i solve this problem? whats wrong with the code? Thank you. As i say, im beginner so sorry for stupid questions. :)
here is the code

```css
h3 {
  color: "blue";
  font-size: "20px";
  font-family: "verdana"
}
p {
  color: "white";
  background: "blue";
  font-family: "helvetica";
  text-indent: "1 cm"
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Pakopinių stilių (CSS) naudojimo pavyzdys</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stiliai.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Trečiojo lygio antraštė</h3>
  <p>Naujas pastraipų stilius.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

First is CSS I called it stiliai.css, secon is html called index.html

Comment: you don't need the add the double quotes to the css values, i.e. `color: blue;` is good, for font only use it when the name has gap inside i.e. `font-family: "helvetica neue";`well, this maybe not related to  you questions above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes wrapping your colors. Quotes are not required while specifying colors.

Change

```css
h3 {color:"blue"; font-size:"20px"; font-family: "verdana"}

to 

h3 {color:blue; font-size:"20px"; font-family: "verdana"}
```

Comment: @netycia: Remove the quotation marks around the font sizes also. They are generally not needed for font names either.

Comment: So quotes are not necessary at all?

Comment: For specifying colors they are not required. Even if you use color codes like #ffffff

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with your use of `"` within your css. These are **not** needed:

```css
h3 {
  color: blue;
  font-size:20px;
  font-family: verdana
}
p {
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  font-family: helvetica;
  text-indent: 10px; /*cm are not commonly used in css*/
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Pakopinių stilių (CSS) naudojimo pavyzdys</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stiliai.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Trečiojo lygio antraštė</h3>
  <p>Naujas pastraipų stilius.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Your use of `"` would only be necessary when you're using the likes of html.

**They are not used in css files**.

Comment: The unit `cm` is used in CSS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Comment: @Guffa: realisitcally though, how often do you actually use that?

Comment: Just because it's unusual doesn't mean that it's wrong.

Comment: @Guffa: Hence 'not commonly used'